# Linkedin API call C#

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to access Linkedin api using C#, but not able to get documents/articles how I can make call to Linkedin API.
I need to get company information using Linkedin API if I pass the company name I need to get the feeds.
Can anyone please direct me how I can proceed further.

Regards
Anand

Comment: I have used Janrain (http://janrain.com/) to this purpose and it is really fine.

Answer (score 1):

This call for get the code:
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=your-client-id&redirect_uri=your-redirect-uri&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile

This call for exchange code to token:
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=your-code&redirect_uri=your-redirect-uri&client_id=your-client-id&client_secret=your-client-secret

And finally this call for get user info:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=your-token&format=json

To take the client id and the client secret, you need sign up to linkedin developer, Here: 
https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer